# centos 7 with Digital ocean vps httpd.service failier

Tags: centos

im try to install phpmyadmin on centos 7  with digitalocean droplet.i edited allow IP to dynamic any IP.but when i try to restart the service,i got this message.

```
[root@centos-512mb-nyc2-01 /]# sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

here is the result after run  systemctl status httpd.service

```
[root@centos /]# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-04-26 04:47:31 EDT; 1min 50s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 2633 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2632 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2632 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 26 04:47:31 centos-512mb-nyc2-01 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 26 04:47:31 centos-512mb-nyc2-01 httpd[2632]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf:
Apr 26 04:47:31 centos-512mb-nyc2-01 httpd[2632]: allow not allowed here
Apr 26 04:47:31 centos-512mb-nyc2-01 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 26 04:47:31 centos-512mb-nyc2-01 kill[2633]: kill: cannot find process ""
Apr 26 04:47:31 centos-512mb-nyc2-01 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 26 04:47:31 centos-512mb-nyc2-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Apr 26 04:47:31 centos-512mb-nyc2-01 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Apr 26 04:47:31 centos-512mb-nyc2-01 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

here is my http file

```
Allow from# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
#
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
         #Require ip 127.0.0.1
        Require all granted
         #Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the one click Application Image that Digital Ocean offers?

You can get the full tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-phpmyadmin-one-click-application-image)